# Convert ArrayList Contents to String with Commas

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, for-loop

Hello fellow programmers,

In my app I just deserialized an ArrayList from a text file and now I have an ArrayList with Strings. For design purposes I want to put the contents of the ArrayList into one organized string with comas and spaces.

I made an attempt at it but he app forcecloses and the LogCat pinpoints the error to this code:

FYI: OptionsText is an empty string and ListOptions is the ArrayList with the strings.

```
public void getOptionsText(){
        int i;
        OptionsText=ListOptions.get(1);
        for(i=2; i<ListOptions.size(); i++){
            OptionsText = OptionsText + ", " + ListOptions.get(i);
        }
        Options.setText(OptionsText);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`ArrayList#toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString%28%29):

```
public void getOptionsText() {
    String OptionsText = ListOptions.toString();
    Options.setText(OptionsText.substring(1, OptionsText.length-1);
}
```

Comment: This assumes `ListOptions` is an `ArrayList`. What if `ListOptions` is a `List`? Since the List implementation is unknown ("program to the interface"), it would be better to use `Arrays.toString`.

Comment: @SteveKuo not really. It assumes that `ListOptions` is an `AbstractCollection`, [an abstract class which pretty much every Java SE collection implementation inherits.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html) Sure, a joiner (Guava/Apache Commons/other) would work; so would a hand-written method. Show me an existing library implementation with a _different_ `toString()` output format; then, we'll talk.

Answer (score 0):

can you please try this...check if list is not null...

```
list.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
```

Comment: This is actually _worse_ than my answer, both in performance and correctness. What if one of the elements of the list's string form contains `'['` or `']'`?

Answer (score 0):

Other than the other answers given by fellow SO users, you can also use the [`join`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#join%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20char%29) method from the `StringUtils` class from `org.apache.commons.lang`.

**OR**

The [`join`](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html#join%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) method from the `Joiner` class from `com.google.common.base`